# Sort Tasks into order of completition

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I saw Jon Skeet give a talk a year or so ago where he showed a snippet of C# 5 that would take a list of Tasks and return them in the order they completed.

It made use of async/await and WhenAny and was quite beautiful but I can't for the life of me remember how it worked.  Now I have need for it.

I'm hoping to figure out how to create a method with a signature similar to this..

```
Task<IEnumerable<T>> InOrderOfCompletion<T>(IEnumerable<T> tasks) where T : Task
```

And could be used as follows:

```
public async Task<int> DelayedInt(int i)
{
    await Task.Delay(i*100);
    return i;
}

[Test]
public async void Test()
{
    Task<int>[] tasks = new[] {5, 7, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4}.Select(DelayedInt).ToArray();
    IEnumerable<Task<int>> ordered = await InOrderOfCompletion(tasks);

    Assert.That(ordered.Select(t => t.Result).ToArray(), Is.EqualTo(new [] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}));
}
```

I've come up with the following but it doesn't feel as simple as I remember

```
    async Task<IEnumerable<T>> InOrderOfCompletion<T>(IEnumerable<T> tasks) where T : Task
    {
        HashSet<Task> taskSet = new HashSet<Task>(tasks);
        List<T> results = new List<T>();
        while(taskSet.Count > 0)
        {
            T complete = (T) await Task.WhenAny(taskSet);
            taskSet.Remove(complete);
            results.Add(complete);
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Do anyone remember know the snippet I'm referring to or how this can be improved upon?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/01/16/eduasync-part-19-ordering-by-completion-ahead-of-time/), [Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/08/02/processing-tasks-as-they-complete.aspx), [and I](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx/3.0.1/net45/doc/Nito.AsyncEx.TaskExtensions/OrderByCompletion''1(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(System.Threading.Tasks.Task(''0)))) all have slightly different approaches. Mine is [available via NuGet](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Nito.AsyncEx) if you don't want to write your own.

Actually, the key is to *avoid* `Task.WhenAny` because that will turn the algorithm from O(N) into O(N^2).

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was after, very clever stuff.