# How to implement Task.WhenAny() with a predicate

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I want to execute several asynchronous tasks concurrently. Each task will run an HTTP request that can either complete successfully or throw an exception. I need to `await` until the first task completes successfully, or until all the tasks have failed.

How can I implement an overload of the [`Task.WhenAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany) method that accepts a predicate, so that I can exclude the non-successfully completed tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static Task<T> GetFirstResult<T>(
    ICollection<Func<CancellationToken, Task<T>>> taskFactories, 
    Predicate<T> predicate) where T : class
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    int completedCount = 0;
    // in case you have a lot of tasks you might need to throttle them 
    //(e.g. so you don't try to send 99999999 requests at the same time)
    // see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25877042/67824
    foreach (var taskFactory in taskFactories)
    {
        taskFactory(cts.Token).ContinueWith(t => 
        {
            if (t.Exception != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Task completed with exception: {t.Exception}");
            }
            else if (predicate(t.Result))
            {
                cts.Cancel();
                tcs.TrySetResult(t.Result);
            }

            if (Interlocked.Increment(ref completedCount) == taskFactories.Count)
            {
                tcs.SetException(new InvalidOperationException("All tasks failed"));
            }

        }, cts.Token);
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
using System.Net.Http;
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await GetFirstResult(
    new Func<CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>>[] 
    {
        ct => client.GetAsync("http://microsoft123456.com", ct),
        ct => client.GetAsync("http://microsoft123456.com", ct),
        ct => client.GetAsync("http://microsoft123456.com", ct),
        ct => client.GetAsync("http://microsoft123456.com", ct),
        ct => client.GetAsync("http://microsoft123456.com", ct),
        ct => client.GetAsync("http://microsoft123456.com", ct),
        ct => client.GetAsync("http://microsoft123456.com", ct),
        ct => client.GetAsync("http://microsoft.com", ct),
        ct => client.GetAsync("http://microsoft123456.com", ct),
        ct => client.GetAsync("http://microsoft123456.com", ct),
    }, 
    rm => rm.IsSuccessStatusCode);
Console.WriteLine($"Successful response: {response}");
```

Comment: Really thank you guys for the quick response and the great engineered solutions. you helped me a lot.

Comment: I am just the protege - you should really thank (and upvote!) my mentor http://stackoverflow.com/a/38289396/67824 ;)

Answer (score 10):

Wait for any task and return the task if the condition is met. Otherwise wait again for the other tasks until there is no more task to wait for.

```
public static async Task<Task> WhenAny( IEnumerable<Task> tasks, Predicate<Task> condition )
{
    var tasklist = tasks.ToList();
    while ( tasklist.Count > 0 )
    {
        var task = await Task.WhenAny( tasklist );
        if ( condition( task ) )
            return task;
        tasklist.Remove( task );
    }
    return null;
}
```

simple check for that

```
var tasks = new List<Task> {
    Task.FromException( new Exception() ),
    Task.FromException( new Exception() ),
    Task.FromException( new Exception() ),
    Task.CompletedTask, };

var completedTask = WhenAny( tasks, t => t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion ).Result;

if ( tasks.IndexOf( completedTask ) != 3 )
    throw new Exception( "not expected" );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static Task<Task<T>> WhenFirst<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks, Func<Task<T>, bool> predicate)
{
    if (tasks == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tasks));
    if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));

    var tasksArray = (tasks as IReadOnlyList<Task<T>>) ?? tasks.ToArray();
    if (tasksArray.Count == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Empty task list", nameof(tasks));
    if (tasksArray.Any(t => t == null)) throw new ArgumentException("Tasks contains a null reference", nameof(tasks));

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Task<T>>();
    var count = tasksArray.Count;

    Action<Task<T>> continuation = t =>
        {
            if (predicate(t))
            {
                tcs.TrySetResult(t);
            }
            if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref count) == 0)
            {
                tcs.TrySetResult(null);
            }
        };

    foreach (var task in tasksArray)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(continuation);
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var task = await WhenFirst(tasks, t => t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);

if (task != null)
    var value = await task;
```

Note that this doesn't propagate exceptions of failed tasks (just as `WhenAny` doesn't).

You can also create a version of this for the non-generic `Task`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more sophisticated version of Ohad Schneider's [`GetFirstResult`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38289158/how-to-implement-task-whenany-with-a-predicate/38291506#38291506) implementation, with similar API as in Eli Arbel's [`WhenFirst`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38289158/how-to-implement-task-whenany-with-a-predicate/38289396#38289396) method. The idea is the same: attach a cancelable continuation on each task, and cancel the `CancellationTokenSource` when a completed task satisfies the `predicate`. This implementation avoids using a [`TaskCompletionSource<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1), and so avoids the risk of the asynchronous `WhenFirst` method never completing because of a bug in the implementation:

```
public static async Task<Task<TResult>> WhenFirst<TResult>(
    Task<TResult>[] tasks,
    Func<Task<TResult>, bool> predicate)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(tasks);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(predicate);

    using CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
    Task<TResult> selectedTask = null;
    IEnumerable<Task> continuations = tasks
        .Where(task => task is not null)
        .TakeWhile(_ => !cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        .Select(task => task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            bool result;
            try { result = predicate(t); } catch { cts.Cancel(); throw; }
            if (result)
                if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref selectedTask, t, null) is null)
                    cts.Cancel();
        }, cts.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach |
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default));

    Task whenAll = Task.WhenAll(continuations);
    try { await whenAll.ConfigureAwait(false); }
    catch when (whenAll.IsCanceled) { } // Ignore
    return selectedTask;
}
```

The selling points of this implementation are:

1. When the `WhenFirst` method completes asynchronously, all the work is done and everything is cleaned up. No continuations are left behind as fire-and-forget tasks, attached on the original tasks.
2. An exception in the `predicate` is propagated as a fault of the returned `Task<Task<TResult>>`.
3. The `predicate` is not called after a task has been selected as the result.
4. In case one of the tasks is already completed and satisfies the `predicate`, continuations are not attached on the remaining tasks (performance optimization).
5. In case none of the tasks satisfies the `predicate`, the asynchronous result of the method is a `null` task. In other words the `WhenFirst().Result` is `null`.
6. The method tolerates `null` tasks in the input `tasks` array. It doesn't throw an exception if it finds a `null` one.

The reason for the signature having as parameter a `Task<T>[]` array instead of an `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` sequence, is because I didn't want to deal with the possibility of an error during the enumeration of the sequence. Passing a deferred sequence as argument, in other words relying on the `WhenFirst()` call to instantiate the tasks, sounds like an improbable scenario to me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this, very similar to [Sir Rufo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38289587/7818969), but using `AsyncEnumerable` and [Ix.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/)

Implement a little helper method to stream any task as soon as it's completed:

```
static IAsyncEnumerable<Task<T>> WhenCompleted<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> source) =>
    AsyncEnumerable.Create(_ =>
    {
        var tasks = source.ToList();
        Task<T> current = null;
        return AsyncEnumerator.Create(
            async () => tasks.Any() && tasks.Remove(current = await Task.WhenAny(tasks)), 
            () => current,
            async () => { });
    });
}
```

One can then process the tasks in completion order, e.g. returning the first matching one as requested:

```
await WhenCompleted(tasks).FirstOrDefault(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
```

Comment: Where is defined this `AsyncEnumerable` class with the `CreateEnumerable`/`CreateEnumerator` methods?

Comment: In Nuget package System.Interactive.Async, edited my answer to mention that. Also realized I was using version 3.1.1, [updated that](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62426036/timeline) to use version 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add on some of the answers @Peebo and @SirRufo that are using List.Remove (because I can't comment yet)

I would consider using:

```
var tasks = source.ToHashSet();
```

instead of:

```
var tasks = source.ToList();
```

so removing would be more efficient

Comment: The `while`+`Task.WhenAny` approach is an antipattern: it is inefficient and doesn't scale well. Trying to optimize it by replacing the `List` with a `HashSet` is unlikely to have any noticeable effect, because too much else is going on (continuations are attached and detached to all remaining tasks on every loop, defensive arrays are allocated, copied and destroyed etc). The best way to optimize this pattern is to not use it.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yup it indeed doesn't look like the most efficient answer here, yet it somehow became the most upvoted, maybe because of simplicity/readability so just wanted to add a little comment on that,
TaskCompletionSource seems like the way to go, thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: Rom yeap, simplicity is certainly an asset, and if you are dealing with ~10 tasks the performance implications are negligible. But if the number of your tasks is ~10,000, Oh my!

Comment: found a cool article about the difference if anyone else wants to drill down : [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/processing-tasks-as-they-complete/)

Comment: Rom indeed, [that's](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/processing-tasks-as-they-complete/) a good reading, but nowadays there are better techniques available for such things (streaming async results in order of completion). Like the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`s and [the channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/). No need to preallocate that many `TaskCompletionSource<Task<T>>`s beforehand!