# How to get the first value that specifies a condition out of multiple tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have a collection of `Task<string>`. I'd like to get the return value of a `Task` that first returns a non-null value.

If I use `Task.WhenAny`, I can get the return value of the `Task` that first completed its execution, but it's impossible to exclude `null` values.

```
private static async Task<string> FirstRespondingTaskAsync(IEnumerable<Task<string>> tasks)
{
    var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
    var data = await completedTask;
    // data can be null, which I'd like to exclude
    return data;
}
```

If I use `Task.WhenAll`, it's possible to exclude `null` values, but I have to wait for all tasks to complete its execution.

```
private static async Task<string> FirstNonNullTaskAsync(IEnumerable<Task<string>> tasks)
{
    var all = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    // I have to wait until all tasks complete
    var data = all.FirstOrDefault(s => s != null);
    return data;
}
```

How can I get the first value that satisfies a specific condition out of multiple tasks?

Comment: what if you do a do while loop, in case its null you await the next completed task

Comment: Isn't this the same question as this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38289158/how-to-implement-task-whenany-with-a-predicate?

Comment: @DimitarD there are better solutions with C# 7

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos reopen and add an answer

Comment: I think it is better to answer the duplicate @TheGeneral

Comment: @PatrickHofman your propensity for logic and rationale is unsettling ;)

Comment: no no, I agree, however its 1130 pm here, and said logic and rationale is evading me atm

Comment: Ah, okay. Got it. Now put your phone in sleep mode and enjoy a good night sleep @TheGeneral ;)

Comment: The duplicate answer is closed as 'too broad', so now the better answer in C#7 can't be provided -- this and any new questions would be duplicates, and the original can't have new answers added.

Comment: @gregmac I voted to reopen that one.