# Multiple Async Functions, First to return the correct result

Tags: .net, vb.net, uwp

I cannot find what I want online and can't find the correct terms for it. So here it is.

I have some amount of async functions:

```
Public Async Function Func1(Arg as T) As Task(Of Reply) 
Public Async Function Func2(Arg as T) As Task(Of Reply)
Public Async Function Func3(Arg as T) As Task(Of Reply)
.
.
```

All of them takes in the same argument and return the same type "Reply".
Within the function,  Reply.Info is allocated with either a valid object or Nothing.

```
Public Class Reply
    Public Property Info As Object = Nothing

    Public ReadOnly Property Available As Boolean
        Get
            Return Info IsNot Nothing
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

I want to do the following without the need to wait for all of the async functions to complete. They can be terminate so as long the first one to complete meets the return criteria - First Non-Nothing Reply.Info.

```
Public Async Function RunFunc(Arg as T) as Task(Of Reply)
    Dim Reply1 As Reply = Await Func2(Arg)
    Dim Reply2 As Reply = Await Func3(Arg)
    Dim Reply3 As Reply = Await Func4(Arg)

'Return the first one where Reply.Available = True
End Function
```

It would be great if someone can provide some insight into this.

**SOLUTION**

Solution based on Richard Zhang's and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49313367/task-whenany-for-non-faulted-tasks)

```
Dim TaskList As New List(Of Task(Of Reply)) From {
    Func1(Search),
    Func2(Search),
    Func3(Search)
}

Dim CompletedTask As Task(Of Reply)
Do
    CompletedTask = Await Task.WhenAny(TaskList.ToArray)
    TaskList.Remove(CompletedTask)
Loop While CompletedTask.IsFaulted AndAlso TaskList.Count > 0
TaskList.Clear()

If Not CompletedTask.IsFaulted Then
    Dim CompletedReply As Reply = Await CompletedTask
    If CompletedReply.Available AndAlso CompletedReply.SomeOtherProperty Then
        Return Reply
    Else
        Return 'Handles non-expected but non-error return
    End If
Else
    Return 'Handles all error situations
End If
```

While not perfect, performance did improve significantly.

Comment: Look up Task.WhenAny()

Comment: [Please do not add "thank you"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/133056).

Comment: How do you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Task.WhenAny` to meet our needs

```vb
Private Async Sub InitTask(Of T)(ByVal Arg As T)
    Dim tasks = New List(Of Task(Of Reply))()
    tasks.Add(Func1(Arg))
    tasks.Add(Func2(Arg))
    tasks.Add(Func3(Arg))
    Dim completeTask = Await Task.WhenAny(tasks.ToArray())
    Dim result = Await completeTask
End Sub
```

Considering that your actual return value may be empty, you can judge whether it is empty in related functions and throw exceptions. Task will filter out the tasks that throw exceptions, and only take the final result.

```vb
Private Async Function Func1(Of T)(ByVal Arg As T) As Task(Of Reply)
    ' get reply
    If reply.Available Then
        Return reply
    Else
        Throw New ArgumentException("not invalid data")
    End If
End Function
```